# Why choose the <div> instead of the <section> for the "wrapper" ID? Is there a difference?

Tags: html

From what I can tell the `<div>` and the `<section>` tags are serving the same purpose? Was this used as an example on how to use the `<div>` tag? If so, are there other purposes for the `<section>` tag? If this wasn't a lesson, would there be use cases to have both?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. If you're referring to some specific lesson, you have to show what it is.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section || https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Comment: Section is basically just a way to group elements on the page.

Comment: The best way to find out about such things is by reading tutorials and w3c recommendations

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly use `<section>` to wrap diffrent module in the page.
Ex.:

- `<section id="news">` containing `<article>` of post
- `<section id="slider">` for an image slider
- `<section id="sitemap">` for the site map

Like we wrap the heading part inside `<header>` and the same for `<footer>`.

Almost all other styling block are `<div>` and `<span>`.

So my body will only contain directly `<header>`, some `<section>` and `<footer>`.

---

Edit/PS:
Reading the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) :

> The HTML  element represents a standalone section — which
> doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it —
> contained within an HTML document. Typically, but not always, sections
> have a heading.

Answer (score -4):

You can even use <orc> and thing does still running normally, depended on script, but that is nothing procedural html form.